# what is the Operating Mode of the EnOcean Occupancy Sensor

Tags: sensors, iot

I have the following Occupancy sensor: [1]

I am confused about its operating behaviour:

1) I read it its document [2]

that it behaves like the following:

*Occupancy Detection and Transmission: If a sensor is already in the occupied mode and continues to detect occupancy it will transmit an occupied telegram every two minutes until occupancy is not detected.

*Unoccupied Transmission: If after sending an occupied telegram a sensor does not detect occupancy for 10 minutes, an unoccupied telegram will be sent.

2) However, in the document of EEP specification [3]

under its EEP profil A5.07.01
a note telling that "The transmission of “PIR off” telegrams is optional"
which mean as I understood that the transmission of the unoccupied message is optional.

3) And in my application, I don't receive the “PIR off” (unoccupied message) as specified in the EEP specification.

-> I don't know if it is a normal behaviour what I get in my application or if there is some configuration that enable the behaviour listed above (in point 1).

Thanks in advance for your help!

[1] https://www.enocean.com/en/enocean_modules/ceiling-mounted-occupancy-sensor-eosc-oem/

[2] https://www.enocean.com/en/enocean_modules/EnOcean_Occupancy_Sensor_Operational_Description_v1.1_05.pdf

[3] http://domotique-info.fr/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/domotique-info-enocean_equipment_profiles_eep_v2.61_public.pdf